# Exclude files from Firebug Profiler?

Tags: javascript, profiling, firebug

Is there a way to exclude a file/scope from Firebug's Profiler?

I would like to profile my app without it looking through jQuery at the same time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not in Firebug. I also have not been privy to any other JS profiler that automatically scopes like this. There is also, a very good reason why profilers don't.

*Assume we could scope so that JQuery isn't profiled*.If you write a function like this:

```
function addThemThenShow( arg1, arg2 )
{
    var result = arg1 + arg2;
    $(result).showAwesomeUiObject();
}
```

You profiler would return and say that addThemThenShow take near 0 time to run. However the JQuery call could do some intensive animation or data work. Maybe that call is from a plugin or something else that you didn't write. However it affects the performance of your site. In this case, it is important to see and realize that maybe use showAwesomeUiObject() is not the way to go.

Comment: Sure. Actually I was lacking in my explanation. Profiling is fine, if there is a way that I can filter jquery out of the results. So that I don't have to look through 300 jquery functions to find 20 of my own. :) If that makes sense.

Comment: Yeap, still no go though. The profiler offers no way to exclude any scripts. I still stand by though, that those 300 pages still carry worth. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The only "solution" I have found thus far is to sort by "File" (far right column header). By no means a perfect solution but at least you could pass over library files (like jQuery, or in my case ExtJS) and get some information.